# Async/Await, aonde está errado?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async, assincronismo

```
const url = 'http://files.cod3r.com.br/curso-js/funcionarios.json'
const axios = require('axios')    

const busca = () =>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
            try{
                const funcionarios = axios.get(url).then(resp => resp.data)
                resolve(funcionarios)
            }
            catch(e){
                reject(e)
            }
        })
     }

    async function getFuncionarios(){


      const funcionarios = await  busca().then(resp => resp)
        return funcionarios
    }

    const fcs = getFuncionarios()
```

`fcs` deveria vir carregado com todos os funcionarios da url, mas só vem o Promise{}.Aonde está o erro ?

`axios.get()` retorna uma promise, eu a resolvo com o then() e jogo o resultado (resp.data) na const funcionarios
    e passo ela no resolve() da minha própria promise. Na outra função deixo ela como async e coloco await na `busca().then(resp => resp)`
resolvendo minha própria promisse e falando para aguardar e depois retorno o resultado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você está utilizando `async/await` não há necessidade de utilizar o `then`:

```
const url = 'http://files.cod3r.com.br/curso-js/funcionarios.json';
const axios = require('axios');

const busca = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(url);
};

const getFuncionarios = async () => await busca();

const fcs = getFuncionarios();
```

Como lembrado pelo [Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio) nos comentários, o valor de retorno de uma função `async` é uma `Promise` então para utilizar o valor você deve utilizar o `then` ou um `await`:

```
(async () => console.log(await getFuncionarios()))();
```

Comment: Sorack, o valor de retorno de um `async` é uma `Promise`.  No teu exemplo `fcs` é uma `Promise`

Comment: Amigo, você esqueceu o return da busca(), mas mesmo com ele não produz o resultado esperado, continua com Promise{<pending>}.

Comment: @Sergio verdade

Comment: Entendi, porém, vai ficar sempre nesse ciclo ? Nunca vou conseguir pegar o valor e armazenar em uma variável que não se torne uma promise ?

Comment: @KevinRicci não, sempre assim.